# Intermittent Failure of ModalView with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I have an `App` that opens a `ModalView` popup from a `Thread` using `Clock.schedule_once()` and uses a `Queue` to wait for the popup dismiss. This works fine about 90% of the time. But occasionally, the thread is waiting for the dismiss without the popup being displayed. This failure only happens when running the `exe` produced by `Pyinstaller`, and only on the first attempt (i.e., the first click on the "Run Test" button). If the first attempt succeeds, then all following attempts also succeed.

I am using:

- Pyinstaller version 3.3.dev0+483c819
- Windows 10

I am developing using Python 3, but `Pyinstaller` produces code that runs Python 2.7.14. The debug output shows only expected differences between success and failure.

This example is distilled from a much more complicated App. If anyone can see the problem, or recommend a more reliable way of opening a `ModalView` from a `Thread`, please let me know.

main.py:

```
import threading

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

from kivy.compat import PY2
if PY2:
    from Queue import Queue
else:
    from queue import Queue


class TestLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestLayout, self).__init__()

    def do_test(self, *arg):
        self.th = AThread()
        self.th.start()


class MyPopup(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.buttonCallback = callback
        dismiss_button = Button(text='Dismiss')
        dismiss_button.bind(on_press=self.butt)
        self.popup = ModalView(size_hint=(.5, .5), auto_dismiss=False)
        self.popup.add_widget(dismiss_button)

    def butt(self, *args):
        if self.popup is not None:
            self.popup.dismiss()
        if self.buttonCallback is not None:
            self.buttonCallback()

    def open(self, *args):
        self.popup.open()


class AThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AThread, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.pop = None
        self.queue = None

    def run(self):
        print('running')
        self.queue = Queue()
        self.pop = MyPopup(lambda: self.queue.put(None, False))
        Clock.schedule_once(self.pop.open)    # This should open the popup, but occasionally it does not
        print('waiting')
        self.queue.get(True)
        print('done waiting')
        self.queue = None


root = Builder.load_string( '''
TestLayout:
    Button:
        text: 'Run Test'
        on_press: root.do_test()
''')


class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root


testApp().run()
```

main.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\John\\PyCharmProjects\\popupbug'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='Test',
          debug=True,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True)
```

Comment: Have you try with `Clock.schedule_once(self.popup.open, -1)` i.e. call before the next frame?

Comment: Yes, I have. I also tried using the @mainthread decorator instead of Clock.schedule_once. All produced the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is that the main thread is hanging in the Kivy `Clock` (verified by doing some tracing) and not actually executing the `self.pop.open` method. This seems to only happen for a `Pyinstaller` produced EXE on Windows. I tested the same code with `Pyinstaller` on Ubuntu, with no failures. The fix/workaround is to use a different kivy `Clock` by inserting the following code at the start of `main.py':

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'kivy_clock', 'interrupt')
```

This makes `kivy` use a different `Clock` and eliminates the problem